# Directory structure of input files getting flattened on output

Tags: javascript, css, coffeescript, sass, gulp

I have a tiered structure in my app/assets/sass/ directory which I am trying to mirror in the CSS output files in `public/css/`, but all the *.scss files in my sass directory and subdirectories are being put into the root `public/css/` folder.

Here is my gulpfile:
When I comment out the lines between `gulp.src(sassDir ...)` and `.pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));` the directory structure is maintained, but the sass is not compiled. Uncommenting the `.pipe(sass(...))` line reproduces the issue.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var coffee = require('gulp-coffee');

var sassDir = 'app/assets/sass/';
var coffeeDir = 'app/assets/coffee/';

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(sassDir + '**/*.scss', { base: sassDir })
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'compress' }).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 versions'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('coffee', function() {
    return gulp.src(coffeeDir + '**/*.coffee', { base: coffeeDir })
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(coffee({ bare: true }).on('error', gutil.log))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/coffee)'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(sassDir + '/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(coffeeDir + '/**/*.coffee', ['coffee']);
});


gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'coffee', 'watch']);
```

Comment: I wrote a answer to this. Look it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33741640/2140095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information of directory structure is kept with 'file.base'. The following code told me that 'gulp-ruby-sass' was changing 'file.base'.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src(sassDir + '**/*.scss')
        .on('data', function (file) { console.log(0, file.base); })
        .pipe(plumber())
        .on('data', function (file) { console.log(1, file.base); })
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'compress' }).on('error', gutil.log))
        .on('data', function (file) { console.log(2, file.base); })
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 versions'))
        .on('data', function (file) { console.log(3, file.base); })
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .on('data', function (file) { console.log(4, file.base); })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});
```

Fortunately this issue has been already reported. It's gonna be fixed soon.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/pull/20

Also, 'base' is supposed to be an absolute path and you don't need to specify '{ base: sassDir }' in this case. It's automatically determined by the given glob pattern.

https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream