# gulp js src - copy and usage of base

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I have gulp task to copy js files

This doesn't work

```
gulp.src('./**/*.js', {base: '../src/main/'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../target/dist'));
```

This works:

```
gulp.src('../src/main/**/*.js', {base: '../src/main/'})
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../target/dist'));
```

So whats the use of base here ? if i have to put whole path in first param, why should i use base ?

is there any official documentation about gulp src ? is it worth using gulp over grunt with limited documentation ?

[UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT]
Why am i using base ?

Please read this
[Looking for way to copy files in gulp and rename based on parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224252/looking-for-way-to-copy-files-in-gulp-and-rename-based-on-parent-directory)

and moreoever gulp.src can take array of paths so i would need base.

Comment: Why are you using `base` in the first place?  It's not in the docs because it's not used except in special circumstances.  `gulp.src` is in the [API docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md), `base` is [documented via `glob-stream`](https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream#options).

Answer (score 21):

The use of `.src()` is documented on the vinyl-fs github repo:
https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs

The `base` property is used to determine the file names when saving in `.dest()`.

**I think you need to set the current working directory**:

```
gulp
  .src('./**/*.js', {cwd: '../src/main/'})
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../target/dist'))
;
```

Answer (score -3):

You should try to use 'root' param instead:

```
 gulp.src('./**/*.js', {root: '../src/main/'})
     .pipe(gulp.dest('../target/dist'));
```