# how to handle assets from different folders in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have list of glob patterns:

```
var assets = [
    '../projects.a/dir1/dir2/file1.js',
    '../projects.b/dir1/dir2/file2.js',
    './app/scripts/dir1/dir2/module.js'
];
```

I want to create a task that will copy all the files that represented by those patterns to my dest folder, **and keep the structure**. For example, in my dest folder I want the following:

```
'dest/projects.a/dir1/dir2/file1.js',
'dest/projects.b/dir1/dir2/file2.js',
'dest/app/scripts/dir1/dir2/module.js'
```

I built the following task:

```
gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src(assets)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

The problem is that I get under 'dest' only one level of directories. For example:\

```
'dest/dir2/file1.js',
'dest/dir2/file2.js',
'dest/dir2/module.js'
```

Any idea what is wrong? How can I solve it?
What is the common approach of handling assets from different folders with gulp?

**UPDATE**
Looking on [Looking for way to copy files in gulp and rename based on parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224252/looking-for-way-to-copy-files-in-gulp-and-rename-based-on-parent-directory), I tried to set `{base: './'}` as a parameter to `gulp.src(assets, {base: './'})` but I get the files that under my current directory nested under another folder. I didn't get the needed behavior. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for way to copy files in gulp and rename based on parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224252/looking-for-way-to-copy-files-in-gulp-and-rename-based-on-parent-directory)

Comment: @Mathletics This is not a duplication. I cannot use the base property since it is different for each file. I am looking for the gulp approach to handle this.

Comment: You may need to use a separate stream for each source; gulp expects to run from the root of your project, but you are trying to reach outside your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the files which are not under the current directory separately. You could use separate tasks, or join streams using `event-stream`:

```
var projectAssets = [
    '../projects.a/dir1/dir2/file1.js',
    '../projects.b/dir1/dir2/file2.js'
];
var assets = [
    './app/scripts/dir1/dir2/module.js'
];

var es = require('event-stream');

gulp.task('scripts', ['clean'], function() {
    return es.merge(gulp.src(assets, {base: './'}), gulp.src(projectAssets, {base: '../'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Comment: This is a good start. The thing is that I have several bases which can be changed. I am looking for a way to get all the bases ('./', '../') from the files paths. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: How would you define 'bases'? Any series of `.` and `..`? What if one of the bases contains some other directory name?

Comment: This is my problem.. I don't manage to define it. I am trying to find a general method that will resolve the base from the path and the current working directory.