# How can I make a copy of a file and move it to the parent folder with gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here is what I have so far it's just a shell as I am not sure how to do this. Would appreciate some advice.

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('copy-move-index', function () {
    return gulp.src('index/index.html')


});
```

Now my index.html file is in the index folder. What I would like to do is to have a task that copies this and moves it to the parent folder.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a duplicate to: [Looking for way to copy files in gulp and rename based on parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do it

```
gulp.src(['your','source','files'])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('output folder'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gulp.dest` in your gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('copy', function () {
    return gulp.src('index/index.html')
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
})
```