# How do I include an external module's images in my react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have an external module (`npm install external-module`) that has it's own images with the given path: `myProject/node_modules/external-module/dist/img`. How do I include these images in my public assets?

Comment: What do u mean by public assets? u want to reference the images inside node_modules in src, href of ur html

Comment: why don't you just create an img folder in your public assets with the images?

Comment: I have to share this module across multiple projects and I would like to ship my images with the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use gulp or grunt to copy the images over from the npm directory to your public assets directory.  This copy operation can run as part of your daily build process or on special occasions like after updates to the node module.

how to copy whole folders:
[Looking for way to copy files in gulp and rename based on parent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224252/looking-for-way-to-copy-files-in-gulp-and-rename-based-on-parent-directory)